# Material Box with carousel-item

Tags: material-design, materialize

I am creating a webpage with multiple image. To store the image I am using the following code.

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider">
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img
                    src="some url"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img
                    src="some url"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img
                    src="some url"></a>
</div>
```

It is working fine. But I want to image in full screen mode once it clicked. for this reason I tried to use materialboxed but it is not working as expected and acting wired. If I add materialboxed class img clicks are not working properly and view is just kind of wired. Is there any way to make it work togather ?

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute class="materialboxed" to the img tags.

```html
  <div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1" class="materialboxed"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2" class="materialboxed"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3" class="materialboxed"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4" class="materialboxed"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5" class="materialboxed"></a>
  </div>
```

And Later initiate it with jquery dependence or not

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
  });
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
  });
```

If using jquery method make sure to Import jquery first